# How to handle exception in case of string

Tags: java, string, exception

I am getting an error when I am entering string value in integer variable. I want to know to handle the exception, as my program give a indication that enter your value again rather it stop and gave exceptional handling error.

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number");
Scanner obj1=new Scanner(System.in);
int a=obj1.nextInt();     //I am entering string value here
System.out.println(a);
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at javaapplication13.JavaApplication13.main(JavaApplication13.java:23)
```

Comment: use a `try-catch` block :)

Answer (score 4):

It is better to preventing throwing exception instead of handling it since creating exception object may be quite expensive. In case of `Scanner` class your code can look like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a number:");

while(!scanner.hasNextInt()){//while user is not providing valid int
    //inform him about it
    System.out.println("that was not valid integer, please try again: ");
    //and consume invalid value (maybe even entire line)
    scanner.nextLine();
}
//since we are out of loop it must mean that user entered valid int, lets store it
int a = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println(a);
```

---

You can also wrap this code in some nice utility method in which you can even add support to *maximal number of tries*. For that kind of code you can use as result `Optional<Integer>`. This will allow us clear info if user

- provided proper value, and we will return Optional with this value
- or if he failed to do so, in which case we can return empty Optional.

which is cleanest way of handling results which *may not exist*.

Without `Optional` we would either have to:

- return some default value like:

  - `-1` but in that case we don't know if `-1` represents invalid input, or if user actually provided `-1` which means it may be proper result
  - `null` (if we change return type to `Integer`) but this way we are making our programmer who will use our method to also check `if(result != null)` which may not be that obvious for many programmers (using `Optional` gives us clear idea that result may not exist so programmer *knows* that he should check this possibility).
- throw exception, but since reason why we are creating our method is to avoid creating and handling exception it would be kind of stupid.

So your method can look like

```
//-1 represents infinite number of tries
public static Optional<Integer> readInt(Scanner sc, String msg, int tries){
    System.out.println(msg);

    int counter = 0;
    //while user still has more tries but is providing invalid int 
    while((tries == -1 || counter < tries) && !sc.hasNextInt()){
        //inform him about wrong data
        if (tries == -1 || ++counter < tries)
            System.out.println("That was not valid integer. Please try again:");
        else
            System.out.println("That was not valid integer.");
        //and consume invalid value (maybe even entire line)
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    // since we are out of loop it must mean that user entered valid int 
    // or run out of tries
    if (tries == -1 || counter < tries)
        return Optional.of(sc.nextInt());
    else
        return Optional.empty();
}
```

and its usage can look like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Optional<Integer> result = readInt(scanner, "Please enter a number:", 1);

if(result.isPresent()){
    System.out.println(result.get());
}else{
    System.out.println("User failed to give valid integer. Program will terminate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    Scanner obj1=new Scanner(System.in);
    if(obj1.hasNextInt())
    {
    int a=obj1.nextInt();     //I am entering string value here
    System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in the try-catch block to handle the `InputMismatchException`

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number");
Scanner obj1=new Scanner(System.in);
try {
  int a=obj1.nextInt();  
}
catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
  /*show error message for incorrect input*/
}
catch(Exception e) {
 /*Show error message*/
}
System.out.println(a);
```

*Hope, this solves the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
 boolean i=true;
    while(i){
    try{
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    Scanner obj1=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=obj1.nextInt();     //I am entering string value here
    System.out.println(a);
    i=false;
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("Invalid number, please enter again");
    }
    }
```